# Adding an [AuthorYear] block at the beginning of bibliography entries

Tags: biblatex

I want to add a block at the beginning of my bib entries of the form

> [Lastnameauthor(s) Year]

When the shortauthor field is defined it should use this field +Year instead. The following example is fairly minimal:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{test.bbx}
\ProvidesFile{test.bbx} 
[\abx@bbxid $Id: test.bbx,v 0.9d 2010/09/03 20:11:58 lehman beta $] 
\RequireBibliographyStyle{authoryear}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{article}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  %---add something here---
  \usebibmacro{author/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \newunit
  \printlist{language}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{bytranslator+others}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{version}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{in:}%
  \usebibmacro{journal+issuetitle}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{note+pages}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
    {\printfield{issn}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}

\endinput
 \end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{MeineBib.bib}
  @article{example,
 author={Firstname Lastname and First Last},
  title={Title},
 journal={Journal},
 year={Year},
  pages={Pages},
} 
  \end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[12pt,ngerman,    ]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[babel,german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage [bibstyle=test]{biblatex}
\bibliography{MeineBib} 
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\cite{example}
\printbibliography\end{document}
```

I'm guessing the solution lies here

```
DeclareBibliographyDriver{article}{%
      \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
      \usebibmacro{begentry}%
      %---add something here---
      \usebibmacro{author/translator+others}%
```

but I can't find out how. It should look like this
[image] which is an existing style (`natdin`) in BibTeX, but not in `biblatex`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Way back, I answered a very similar question at the German-speaking forum [mrunix.de](http://mrunix.de/forums/showthread.php?t=67067). The trick is to add `\usebibmacro{cite}` to the bibmacro `begentry` (which does nothing by default). Then choose the citestyle authoryear and the bibliography style authortitle, sort the bibliography by author-year-title, remove dashes for recurrent authors ... and you're set. ;-)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[citestyle=authoryear-comp,bibstyle=authortitle,sorting=nyt,dashed=false,%
    maxcitenames=1]{biblatex}

\newcounter{mymaxcitenames}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \setcounter{mymaxcitenames}{\value{maxnames}}%
}

\renewbibmacro*{begentry}{%
  \printtext[brackets]{%
    \begingroup
    \defcounter{maxnames}{\value{mymaxcitenames}}%
    \printnames{labelname}%
    \setunit{\nameyeardelim}%
    \usebibmacro{cite:labelyear+extrayear}%
    \endgroup
    }%
  \quad% or \addspace
}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{first-last}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{biblatextest.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A. and Buthor, B.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{biblatextest.bib}

\begin{document}

Some text \autocite{A01}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

EDIT: Improved redefinition of `begentry` to allow for cases where `maxnames` differs between in-text-citations and the bibliography. (`\defcounter` is an [etoolbox](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/etoolbox.html) macro that allows [in contrast to `\setcounter`] for *local* redefinitions of counter values.)

EDIT 2: Removed need to manually set custom counter.

EDIT 3: Changed format of author names to `first-last`.

EDIT 4: Replaced `\usebibmacro{cite}` with lower-level commands in order to make example also work with `comp` styles (which compress recurring author names in citations).

(In case anyone is wondering about these piecemeal enhancements: This question has become sort of a "Parallel Campaign" to another question at [mrunix.de](http://mrunix.de/forums/showthread.php?t=70006).)

Comment: @ lockstep: Thanks a lot! As it turns out, my thoughts were way tooo complicated...

Comment: Just to mention - I hope to implement user-definable labelapha in biber soon and so these labels will be customisable.

Comment: The `\usebibmacro{cite:labelyear+extrayear}%` should be replaced by `\printfield{labelyear}% \printfield{extrayear}%` for the entry not to be linked, since links doesnt make sence in the bibliography

Comment: When trying this minimal example I get
    `! Package keyval Error: maxcitenames undefined.`
Is this a problem with the version of biblatex?

Comment: @pirad Very likely, as `maxcitenames` was added in `biblatex` v1.1. Add `\listfiles` at the start of the MWE, compile and check the logfile for your version number.

Comment: @lockstep True it says `biblatex 2010/03/19 v0.9a programmable bibliographies`. Thanks.

Comment: When I add `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`, the bib entries don't indent anymore on breaks. This is strange...

Comment: @lockstep: would it then be possible to remove the author field in your solution to get [Author et al. 2001] Alpha. 2001. ?

Comment: @pluton Add `\renewbibmacro*{author}{}`.