# biblatex: Set citation options on a cite-by-cite basis

Tags: biblatex, author-number

Here's the deal: I have a `biblatex` bibliography with a prenote. The prenote contains a citation with a lot of authors. I want it to behave as if it were obeying `maxnames=3`. But I want my bibliography to behave as if `maxnames=99`. Is there a way to set the value of `maxnames` locally for that one citation?

More generally, is there a procedure for locally setting `biblatex` options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the first time I encountered a citation command within the bibliography. Note: `\defcounter` (an etoolbox macro) instead of `\setcounter` allows for local redefinition of counters. (EDIT: I used the same hack in my [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11827/add-block-in-bibliography-entry/11856#11856) to [Adding an [AuthorYear] block at the beginning of bibliography entries](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11827/adding-an-authoryear-block-at-the-beginning-of-bibliography-entries) .)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authoryear,maxnames=99,maxcitenames=3]{biblatex}

\newcounter{mymaxcitenames}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \setcounter{mymaxcitenames}{\value{maxnames}}% i.e., 3 (!)
}

\defbibnote{recommended}{If you don't have time to read anything else, read
  \begingroup
  \defcounter{maxnames}{\value{mymaxcitenames}}%
  \textcite{A01}.%
  \endgroup
}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{biblatextest.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A. and Buthor, B., and Cuthor, C. and Duthor, D.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{biblatextest.bib}

\begin{document}

If you don't have time to read anything else, read \textcite{A01}.

\printbibliography[prenote=recommended]

\end{document}
```

Comment: @lockstep the reason for the citation in the prenote is to reference where the figures in the paper are originally found. I'd have thought that wasn't _that_ uncommon...

Comment: @Seamus: If my answer wasn't useful for you, I'd like to hear how to sharpen it up.

Comment: @lockstep I actually think `maxcitenames` will solve my problem on its own, won't it? I don't think my version of biblatex has it though, so I will have to update... I'll check back later.

Comment: @Seamus: For versions <1.1, delete the `maxnames` and `maxcitenames` preamble options, add `[maxnames=99]` to `\printbibliography` and try again.

Comment: @lockstep I've updated to 1.2a. Citations in the prenote inherit their cite style from the printbibliography command, so annoyingly, a \cite inside the prenote prints all the authors. I'll try your solution in a while...

Comment: @lockstep This works thanks. Why doesn't the prenote respond to `maxcitenames` rather than `maxbibnames`? That seems strange. Especially given the fact that prenote _doesn't_ respect `\bibfont`. That seems inconsistent...