# biblatex name format that recedes to 'et al.' immediately

Tags: biblatex, author-number

I am having my `biblatex` defaults to switch to 'et al.' rather late (past three authors). Now I have occasions where the repeated mention of an author asks for a short form 'Author et al.', irrespective of the number of co-authors. I already use a custom name format like this:

```
\DeclareNameFormat{idem}{%
  \usebibmacro{name:last}{#1}{#3}{#5}{#7}%
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}
```

How would I create another name format, say with `\DeclareNameFormat{short}` that always resorts to 'et al.' if there is more than one author; without changing my global `biblatex` style settings (`maxnames` -- don't want to touch it!). Is there any other macro than `name:andothers` that I can use?

---

The answer of @lockstep gets close. But I want to have `\citeauthor{A01}` behave normally, except for cases where I repeat the authors multiple times. I can of course add a duplicate entry with this technique; still I wonder if I can get the following 'naive' idea taken from that answer to work:

```
\newcommand{\personshort}[1]{\defcounter{maxnames}{1}\citeauthor{#1}}
```

This 'works' but seems to overwrite `maxnames` for the rest of the document. how would I encapsulate the defcounter to be effective only inside this `\newcommand`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of defining a special name format, I suggest the following:

- Define a new bibliography category and add the "special occasion" keys to it,
- Use `\AtEveryCitekey` to test for this category and, if true, set `maxnames` to 1 *locally*  (using `\defounter` from the `etoolbox` package, which is loaded by `biblatex`).

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\DeclareBibliographyCategory{alwaysetal}
\addtocategory{alwaysetal}{A01}

\AtEveryCitekey{%
  \ifcategory{alwaysetal}{%
    \defcounter{maxnames}{1}%
  }{%
  }%
}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {A and B and C},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
@misc{D02,
  author = {D and E and F},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Bravo},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\cite{A01}

\cite{D02}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, lockstop. The `defcounter` seems to do the trick, but can I use it within a dedicated command instead of adding particular bibliography entries to a category (see my edited question)?

Answer (score 3):

Using the above answer along with another [related answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12846/set-citation-options-on-a-cite-by-cite-basis-in-biblatex) from @lockstep, I arrived at the following, which seems to be what I want:

```
\newcommand{\personshort}[1]{\begingroup%
\defcounter{maxnames}{1}\citeauthor{#1}%
\endgroup}
```

This temporarily sets the `maxnames` count to one, and I have a dedicated command `\personshort` for the occasions where I want the fallback to 'at al.' immediately.

---

In my wider context I use a `\person` command with two arguments, the latter being the name format (called `\formatname` in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57636/macro-for-formatting-names-initials-or-full-name)). I was able then to change that do conditionally use the above command instead of a name format:

```
\newcommand*{\person}[2]{%
  \ifstrequal{#2}{short}{\personshort{#1}}{\citename{#1}[#2]{author}}%
}
```

So I have for example `\person{miller1960plans}{sci}` for the longest format, using initials and up to three names, then `\person{miller1960plans}{idem}` for normal repetitions, leaving out the initials, and `\person{miller1960plans}{short}` for the coercion to 'et al' despite a number of co-authors smaller than or equal to `maxnames`.

- *sci:* G. A. Miller, E. Galanter and K. H. Pribram
- *idem:* Miller, Galanter and Pribram
- *short:* Miller et al.