# biblatex short title and long title in bibliography

Tags: biblatex

Is it possible to customize the bibliography (at the end of the document) so that references are shown as follows:

```
  Author_A short_title  
       Author_A long_title
```

Short titles are used throughout the document. `biblatex` with `style=authortitle-comp` is used. It is difficult to relate the short titles to the normal long title in the bibliography when reading the document. It is therefore required that the author name and the short title should precede the full references in the bibliography for ease of reference.

The solution by @lockstep work, but there is one issue. The layout is incorrect in that there is not a space between the author and the title. In addition the author references are mulched. Please see the screenshot here.

[image: Mulched references]

Bibtex was upgraded as per @lockstep's note hereunder and all issues were resolved. Well almost ...

[image]

What can be done to get rid of the dot at the start of every reference, see the example here:

[image]

Comment: does the package jurabib help?

Comment: The jurabib package was previously used and was later replaced with biblatex.

Comment: @INTINV: Choosing `style=reading` will simply override any style choosen previously. "Tweaking" the `reading` style to your liking is probably more difficult than fixing the missing space between author and title shown in your first screenshot. With regard to this screenshot: Please provide a compilable example that shows the faulty behaviour instead. I tested my example with the `hyperref` package added, and things still work as expected.

Comment: ! Package keyval Error: maxcitenames undefined.
See the keyval package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
l.7850 \blx@processoptions ------- It might be a problem with this Latex/Biblatex installation? Thanks @lockstep

Comment: `maxcitenames` was introduced in biblatex v1.1, so you should update your installation.

Comment: Biblatex was upgraded and your solution work, thank you @lockstep.

Comment: The brackets were removed by slightly changing @locksteps code: '\usepackage[style=authortitle-comp,hyperref=true,backref=true,abbreviate=true,dashed=false,maxcitenames=1,backend=bibtex8]{biblatex}
\newcounter{mymaxcitenames}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \setcounter{mymaxcitenames}{\value{maxnames}}%
}
\renewbibmacro*{begentry}{%
%  \printtext[brackets]{%
  \printtext{%
    \begingroup
    \defcounter{maxnames}{\value{mymaxcitenames}}%
    \printnames{labelname}%
    \setunit{\nametitledelim}%
    \usebibmacro{cite:title}%
    \endgroup
    }%
  \newline% or \quad\ or \addspace
}'

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have answered a similar question about [modifying author-year bibliographies](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11827/add-block-in-bibliography-entry). When trying to adapt my former answer to `authortitle-comp`, I noticed that using a `comp` style (which compresses recurring author names in citations) presents an additional difficulty: One cannot simply use `\usebibmacro{cite}` when customizing the bibliography format, but must resort to lower-level commands. The following seems to work:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authortitle-comp,dashed=false,maxcitenames=1]{biblatex}

\newcounter{mymaxcitenames}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \setcounter{mymaxcitenames}{\value{maxnames}}%
}

\renewbibmacro*{begentry}{%
  \printtext[brackets]{%
    \begingroup
    \defcounter{maxnames}{\value{mymaxcitenames}}%
    \printnames{labelname}%
    \setunit{\nametitledelim}%
    \usebibmacro{cite:title}%
    \endgroup
    }%
  \newline% or \quad\ or \addspace
}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{first-last}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{biblatextest.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A. and Buthor, B.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {A sophisticated and verbose theory of Alpha},
  shorttitle = {Alpha},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{biblatextest.bib}

\begin{document}

Some text \autocite{A01}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

EDIT: Replaced `\quad` with `\newline`. Please specify what other part of the layout is "incorrect".

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer @lockstep. The question was edited. Would you possibly take another look at it?