# biblatex: how to add a key with authoyear style

Tags: biblatex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Adding an [AuthorYear] block at the beginning of bibliography entries](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11827/adding-an-authoryear-block-at-the-beginning-of-bibliography-entries)

I use biblatex on Ubuntu 11.04 (TeXLive 2009, biblatex 0.9, no biber).
The style is authoyear.

In the bibliography, I would like to add a key [AuthorYear] in front of the citation (like the apalike style in bibtex).

I think it's possible without updating everything but I don't understand the numerous options in biblatex.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want a fully apa compliant bibliography with biblatex? If so, there is the biblatex-apa style...

Comment: Yes I know but it requires biblatex 1.4 (and I don't want to update everything).

Comment: I did the update a few days ago. It is quite easy and painless. Unless you have done tons of tweaking in internal files and that you don't remember them, you really should do it.

Comment: Yeah, I will reconsider it.

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11827/adding-an-authoryear-block-at-the-beginning-of-bibliography-entries) question.

Comment: Do you have any idea on how to put the key in its own column (like in numeric style)?