# Change token of biblatex alphabetic style

Tags: biblatex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Adding an [AuthorYear] block at the beginning of bibliography entries](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11827/adding-an-authoryear-block-at-the-beginning-of-bibliography-entries)

I have used `biblatex` for some time with the `alphabetic` style for my work. But now I have to change the token (e.g. [KK09]) in front of the items of the bibliography to a longer version:

On two authors it should look like this: [Author1 Author2, Year]

With three or more authors: [Author1 et. al., Year]

Furthermore I'd like to change the citation style over `\cite{}` in the same way.

I took a look at some sites, read in the `biblatex` documentation and tried on my own. But I saw that I need some help.

If you need a short example, please give me a hint and I will post one.

Comment: It looks like you want to move to a roughly `authoryear`-type bibliography style

Comment: Yes, that´s right. But this style has no token in front of each bibliography item. Or is it needless in this style?
How can I change the citation style to
[Authors, Year]?

Comment: Normally, an [Author, Year] block isn't needed for `authoryear` styles. That said, have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11827/adding-an-authoryear-block-at-the-beginning-of-bibliography-entries

Comment: Thank you for the link! But I think so too. Redundant information. I will talk to my Prof, perhaps I can bring him around.

When I use \autocite in the text, authoryear cites like this "(Name, Year)" and Year has a hyperref link to the bibliography. I´d like a link over the whole cite. Is there another command to do this? Or what do I have to change?

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15951/hyperlink-name-with-biblatex-authoryear-biblatex-1-4b

Answer (score 3):

Thank you for your comments. After them, I saw that I was overwhelmed from the option and possibilities of `biblatex`. Furthermore I use the "old" cite commands.

After afresh look in the biblatex documentation, I now use the `authoryear` style and the `\textcite` and `\parencite` commands, which do what I want.