# Biblatex style: use '=' in final bibliography

Tags: biblatex

I'm afraid this is a stupid question, but browsing Biblatex styles I could not find an answer. The editor of a book wants this from contributors:

> TEXT
>  as noticed by Ross 2003, p. 75

---

> FINAL BIBLIOGRAPHY
>  Ross 2003 = M. Ross, *History of China*,
>   Berlin 2003

For the text I used a standard authortitle style, and it's all right. Is there a style for what the editor wants in the final list? It's a bit unusual, I'm afraid.

I add a MWE and an image of the output that I get with a normal authoryear style.[image: output]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
  @book{Ross86,
    author = {Ross, Mark},
    year = {1986},
     title = {History of {C}hina},
     location = {Berlin},
     publisher = {Bla Verlag},
  }
\end{filecontents}
%
\usepackage[style=authoryear,%
% personal options
doi=false,%
isbn=false,%
url=false,
]{biblatex}
% omit publisher:
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearlist{publisher}}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
This is very important, as noticed by \textcite[65]{Ross86}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I think it is quite safe to say that there is no such style, but it should not be too hard to implement this feature. But in order to do so, we would need to know what base style to modify (should it not be `authoryear` or friends instead of `authortitle`), also we need to know about other modifications to the bibliography/citations. So a MWE would really be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take my [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/11856/510) to [Adding an [AuthorYear] block at the beginning of bibliography entries](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11827/adding-an-authoryear-block-at-the-beginning-of-bibliography-entries) and replace my redefinition of the `begentry` bibmacro with the following redefinition:

```
\renewbibmacro*{begentry}{%
  \printtext{%
    \begingroup
    \defcounter{maxnames}{\value{mymaxcitenames}}%
    \printnames{labelname}%
    \setunit{\nameyeardelim}%
    \usebibmacro{cite:labelyear+extrayear}%
    \endgroup
    }%
  \addspace=\addspace
}
```

Comment: Solved my question. Could this be transformed into a new style? I think it might be useful.