# Add square brackets to authoryear bibstyle

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, citing, biber

I am trying to get square brackets for both all cite references in the text and in my bibliography list at the end of my document.

I have got the square brackets for the cite refs inside the text working as you can reproduce with my sample document:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[scaled]{}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[
    bibstyle=authoryear,
    citestyle=authoryear,
    backend=biber,
    sortlocale=de_DE,
    natbib=true,
    url=true,
    doi=true,
    eprint=true,
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}


\makeatletter

\newrobustcmd*{\parentexttrack}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \blx@blxinit
  \blx@setsfcodes
  \blx@bibopenparen#1\blx@bibcloseparen
  \endgroup}

\AtEveryCite{%
  \let\parentext=\parentexttrack%
  \let\bibopenparen=\bibopenbracket%
  \let\bibcloseparen=\bibclosebracket}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{The first chapter}
As \parencite{Sattler} pointed out...


\nocite{*}
\printbibliography


\end{document}
```

However I need to have additional square brackets containing the cite reference in the bibliography list as shown here:

[image: Screenshot illustrating desired bibstyle]

For the sake of completeness here is a small sample snippet of my bib-file:

```
%% Saved with string encoding Unicode (UTF-8)
@book{Sattler,
    Address = {Weinheim},
    Author = {Sattler, Klaus},
    Date-Added = {2013-09-28 21:46:33 +0200},
    Date-Modified = {2013-09-28 21:46:33 +0200},
    Isbn = {35272627271},
    Publisher = {VCH Verlagsgesellschaft},
    Title = {Thermische Trennverfahren: Grundlagen, Auslegung, Apparate},
    Year = {1988}}

@book{Schwister,
    Address = {M{\"u}nchen},
    Author = {Schwister, Karl},
    Date-Added = {2013-09-24 12:32:57 +0200},
    Date-Modified = {2013-09-24 12:33:09 +0200},
    Edition = {4., aktualisierte Aufl},
    Isbn = {9783446424357},
    Publisher = {Fachbuchverlag Leipzig im Carl-Hanser-Verlag},
    Title = {Taschenbuch der Verfahrenstechnik: mit 49 Tabellen},
    Year = {2010}}
```

How can I achieve those additional reference listings in the bibliography (like having in `bibstyle=alphabetic` or `bibstyle=numeric`)?

Comment: Maybe [Adding an AuthorYear block at the beginning of bibliography entries](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11827/35864),  [Revisiting: “Adding an AuthorYear block at the beginning of bibliography entries”](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/303519/35864), [squared bracketed citation in references list](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/178905/35864) and [Biblatex style: use '=' in final bibliography](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/209932/35864) can help you. (Your question is practically a duplicate of the first one.)

Comment: Actually the first link you provided solved the question.