# Biblatex matching reference citations and labels

Tags: biblatex

I am customising my PhD bibliography with `biblatex` and I face the following problem: I want to keep a **consistency** between the **citations** in the text and the **label names** in the list of references, so that the reader quickly recognises the citation by its label.

This works very well if I limit the `maxcitenames` and `maxalphanames` to `1`, by defining the master number to `maxnames=1` then in order to keep all the authors in the reference, I define `maxbibnames=20`.

[image]

However, for `maxnames=2` or more, it doesnt seem to work, even after defining `maxalphanames=2` explicitly

[image]

Any solution/comment is welcome
Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage [backend=bibtex,style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{refs.bib}
@article{a,
    title = {first publication},
    journal = {a first journal},
    author = {A},
    year = {2000},
}
@article{b,
    title = {second publication},
    journal = {a second journal},
    author = {X and C},
    year = {1988},
}
@article{c,
    title = {third publication},
    journal = {a third journal},
    author = {O and P and Q},
    year = {2006},
}
@article{h,
    title = {Observations of ingot macrosegregation on model systems},
    journal = {Metallurgical Transactions},
    author = {Hebditch, D. J. and Hunt, J. D.},
    year = {1974},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{refs}
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{ minnames=1, maxnames=2,                            
                            maxbibnames=20,
                            }

%define label before reference in list  
\renewbibmacro{begentry}{%
\textbf{(\printnames[][-\value{liststop}]{labelname}~\printfield{labelyear}\printfield{extrayear}})\\}

\begin{document}
\parencite{a} \\
\parencite{b} \\
\parencite{c} \\
\parencite{h} \\
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Does [Adding an AuthorYear block at the beginning of bibliography entries](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11827/35864) help? Especially the construction with `mymaxcitenames`?

Comment: This is perfect ! However, can you add it as answer and briefly explain why it works with `mymaxcitenames` defined locally, while not with `maxalphanames`?

Comment: The option `maxalphanames` applies only to the `alphabetic` style and cannot help us here. In order for `biblatex` to allow us to use the exact same commands to print names in citations and in the bibliography it changes an internal "citename" counter as soon as we get into bibliography territory (outside of a bibliography a "normal" citation is assumed). Thus all commands executed in the bibliography will use the same name settings, we can prevent this by locally redefining the value of this `maxnames` counter.