# BibLaTex: Adding a non-hyperlinked authoryear block before each bibliography entry

Tags: biblatex, hyperref

I would like to add an `[Author(s) Year]` block at the beginning of every citation, exactly as described in this question: [Adding an [AuthorYear] block at the beginning of bibliography entries](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11827/adding-an-authoryear-block-at-the-beginning-of-bibliography-entries).

I used the very code given in the accepted answer to that question. However, in addition, I want my citations to be hyperlinked, and therefore use the package `hyperref`. The following is a minimal working example which demonstrates my problem:

```
\documentclass{article}

% Adding a yearauthor block in bibliohraphy: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/11856/42810
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,citestyle=authoryear,bibstyle=authortitle,sorting=nyt,dashed=false,maxcitenames=2]{biblatex}

\newcounter{mymaxcitenames}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \setcounter{mymaxcitenames}{\value{maxnames}}%
}

\renewbibmacro*{begentry}{%
  \printtext[brackets]{%
    \begingroup
    \defcounter{maxnames}{\value{mymaxcitenames}}%
    \printnames{labelname}%
    \setunit{\nameyeardelim}%
    \usebibmacro{cite:labelyear+extrayear}%
    \endgroup
    }%
  \addspace%
}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{first-last}

% Use hyperref to hyperlink citations
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[hyperindex=true]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,linkcolor=Blue,citecolor=BrickRed}


\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{foo,
  author    = {Grace Murray Hopper},
  title     = {The Education of a Computer},
  journal   = {{IEEE} Annals of the History of Computing},
  volume    = {9},
  number    = {3/4},
  pages     = {271--281},
  year      = {1987}
}
\end{filecontents}

\bibliography{\jobname}

\begin{document}

Here is a citation: \cite{foo}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

This produces the following:
[image]

As you can see, the authoryear block in the bibliography contains a hyperlink to itself. I do not want this hyperlink, although I do want the hyperlink in the running text (i.e., before the bibliograpy). How can I remove the hyperlink from the authoryear block in the bibliography?

Comment: Is the hyperlink really that bad?

Comment: For me, yes. :) There has to be some way around this?

Comment: Yes, there definitely is. But I thought it might be easier to talk you out of it than to find the solution.  `;-)`But alas, ... let me see what I can do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We only need to make the `bibhyperref` format do nothing in the "introductory" block. To this end we insert `\DeclareFieldFormat{bibhyperref}{##1}%` (the double `#` is necessary because we are already within a macro definition) into the redefinition of `begentry`

```
\renewbibmacro*{begentry}{%
  \printtext[brackets]{%
    \begingroup
    \DeclareFieldFormat{bibhyperref}{##1}%
    \defcounter{maxnames}{\value{mymaxcitenames}}%
    \printnames{labelname}%
    \setunit{\nameyeardelim}%
    \usebibmacro{cite:labelyear+extrayear}%
    \endgroup
    }%
  \addspace%
}
```

This gives the desired result

```
\documentclass{article}

% Adding a yearauthor block in bibliohraphy: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/11856/42810
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,citestyle=authoryear,bibstyle=authortitle,sorting=nyt,dashed=false,maxcitenames=2]{biblatex}

\newcounter{mymaxcitenames}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \setcounter{mymaxcitenames}{\value{maxnames}}%
}

\renewbibmacro*{begentry}{%
  \printtext[brackets]{%
    \begingroup
    \DeclareFieldFormat{bibhyperref}{##1}%
    \defcounter{maxnames}{\value{mymaxcitenames}}%
    \printnames{labelname}%
    \setunit{\nameyeardelim}%
    \usebibmacro{cite:labelyear+extrayear}%
    \endgroup
    }%
  \addspace%
}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{first-last}

% Use hyperref to hyperlink citations
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[hyperindex=true]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,linkcolor=Blue,citecolor=BrickRed}


\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{foo,
  author    = {Grace Murray Hopper},
  title     = {The Education of a Computer},
  journal   = {{IEEE} Annals of the History of Computing},
  volume    = {9},
  number    = {3/4},
  pages     = {271--281},
  year      = {1987}
}
\end{filecontents}

\bibliography{\jobname}

\begin{document}
Here is a citation: \cite{foo}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Note that nowadays Biber is the preferred backend (BibTeX does not support the full set of `biblatex` features). Starting from version 3.3 of `bibaltex` `\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{first-last}` should be replaced by `\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{given-family}`. `\bibliography{\jobname}` can (should) be replaced by `\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}` (note that this includes the file ending).