# bibliography with exact citation form

Tags: biblatex, biber

Using biblatex with author-year style, I need a bibliography which outputs not only the normal bibliography entry, but the short citation form like from \cite as well, seperated by a colon:

[image: example 01]

The example above is simply made with

```
\cite{96}:
\printbibliography[heading=none]
```

but of course I can't do this for every single entry of my bibliography, and there should be no linebreak behind the colon.
How can I achieve this with biblatex?

### MWE

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
@book{3,
 editor = {Ball, M.},
 title = {The Celtic Languages},
 publisher = {Routledge},
 location = {London},
 date = {1993},}
@book{5,
 author = {Borooah, A.},
 title = {English-Sanskrit Dictionary},
 publisher = {Publication board},
 location = {Assam},
 date = {1971},}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear,useprefix=true,dashed=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{test.bib}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\begin{document}
I need the bibliography to look like this (but with the author's surname first after the colon):

\cite{3}: \fullcite{3}

\cite{5}: \fullcite{5}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Something like in [Adding an [AuthorYear] block at the beginning of bibliography entries](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11827/35864)? We could attempt a more specific answer if you could give us an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) to play round with. (Are you using `style=authoryear` or something more fancy, do you have any other modifications to your `biblatex` setup that could be relevant etc. etc.)

Comment: @moewe I tried this, but it outputs a different version of the bibliography entry and of course I can't use this to output a list of entries. However, `\cite{foo1}: \fullcite{foo1}\newline\cite{foo2}: \fullcite{foo2}\newline …` is the best I got so far…

Comment: Sorry, I think I misread your question when I suggested `\fullcite`. Can you check my edited first comment again? Does the linked question help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it with the help of [moewe's comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/336346/bibliography-with-exact-citation-form/336368#comment824647_336346) and [11827](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11827) by adding:

```
\renewbibmacro*{begentry}{%
  \printtext{%
    \begingroup%
    \printnames{labelname}%
    \setunit{\nameyeardelim}%
    \usebibmacro{cite:labelyear+extrayear}%
    \endgroup%
    }%
  \addcolon\space%
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: ... and don't forget to accept your own answer by clicking the checkmark, in that way your question will no longer appear on the UNanswered list! :)

Comment: OK, don't forget to do it in 2 days hahaha!

Answer (score 0):

Try this (of course you have to refine the `\ifnameundef` if you have other cases):

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
@book{3,
 editor = {Ball, M.},
 title = {The Celtic Languages},
 publisher = {Routledge},
 location = {London},
 date = {1993},}
@book{5,
 author = {Borooah, A.},
 title = {English-Sanskrit Dictionary},
 publisher = {Publication board},
 location = {Assam},
 date = {1971},}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear,useprefix=true,dashed=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{test.bib}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\AtEveryBibitem{\vspace{10pt}
    \ifnameundef{author}
    {\printnames{editor}}
    {\printnames{author}}%
    \addspace    \printfield{year}: \item}

\begin{document}
I need the bibliography to look like this (but with the author's surname first after the colon):

\cite{3}: \fullcite{3}

\cite{5}: \fullcite{5}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but this does not solve the problem correctly: I needed it to output the exact citation form, which prints just the author's surname and can include disambiguation letters. I solved it using [11827](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11827) now.

Comment: @dessert OK, I'm glad you've already solved your problem. I leave my answer as a possible alternative, even if the correct way is the one moewe showed you.