# How can i recreate this certain citestyle via biblatex/biber

Tags: biblatex, citing, biber

I need some help in order to fulfill the style requirements of my university. They require me to use this style of citation for my thesis.
Unfortunately my skills in using BibLaTeX are quite limited...
Could someone pleas explain me how to accomplish this task?
Thanks in advance!

The citation style should look like the screenshot on the left, so the question is what changes have to be made in order to get:

a) the Citations in brackets, (not the citekeys)

b) those keys into the bibliography at the end

c) notes into the footnote, (e.g page)

[image: comp.]

Here the working Minimum Example

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper, openany]{scrbook}
\usepackage[natbib=true,sortcites=true,backend=biber,bibstyle=alphabetic, 
citestyle=authoryear,sorting=nty]{biblatex} 
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpretobibmacro{title}{\begingroup\bfseries}{}{}
\xapptobibmacro{title}{\endgroup}{}
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{%
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{key,
author = {Author, A.},
year = {2001},
title = {Title},
publisher = {Publisher},
}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
blablablabla blablabla here comes a cite \cite{key} \\
blablabla blabla here's the \footcite{key}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! How far could you get on your own? Can you compile a document using `biblatex` and its `authoryear` style? What exactly needs changing? You will find that many of the changes your style needs have been covered on this site.

Comment: Hi, yes i already compiled the document with option "authoryear" activated, but that doesn't look like the required citestyle at all...

Comment: Aha! But you have something and you already applied some changes. Please show us the code you use now in an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)/[MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864) that way we can get started more quickly. But please remember this is not a 'do it for me forum', this is a Q&A site. So questions should ideally revolve around one well-defined specific issue like 'how can I get square brackets around citations'. 'How can I obtain this style', is not the best kind of question here.

Comment: For footnotes you can use the option `autocite=footnote` and then use `\autocite`. That will not give you the square brackets though, but really the square brackets look odd if there is only a citation in the footnote.

Comment: To show what you have so far, you can also upload your current code and the citation style requirements (I assume youhave that as a pdf) to some repository and ask someone to have a look at it. You might get some advice for a few of the style commands this way. Ask about the rest of the details here in each a separate question per specific problem. This might be ne of the more efficient ways of recreating a certain citation style. Your desired style might _already_ be closer to another style than authoryear.

Answer (score 1):

With `biblatex-ext`<sup>1</sup> you can get started like this

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,
  citestyle=ext-authoryear, bibstyle=ext-authortitle, sorting=nyt,
  introcite=plain]{biblatex} 
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DeclareFieldFormat{bbx@introcite}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}
\renewcommand*{\introcitepunct}{\quad}

\DeclareOuterCiteDelims{parencite}{\bibopenbracket}{\bibclosebracket}

\begin{document}
\autocite{sigfridsson}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: The citation reads "[Sigfridsson und Ryde 1998]", the bibliography entry "[Sigfridsson und Ryde 1998] Sigfridsson, Emma und Ulf Ryde. „Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the electrostatic potential and moments“. In: Journal of Computational Chemistry 19.4 (1998), S. 377–395. doi: 10.1002/(SICI)1096-987X(199803)19:4<377::AID-JCC1>3.0.CO;2-P."]

This does not deal with footnote citations consisting only of the label wrapped in square brackets, because I found that odd. But it is possible to add that as well (not with `\DeclareOuterCiteDelims` yet, though).

---

<sup>1</sup>Yes, this is an ad. I wrote the styles.

Answer (score 0):

Putting this in your preamble will add the citation label and year to the beginning of each bibliography item in parentheses.

```
\renewbibmacro*{begentry}{%
    \textsc{\usebibmacro{cite}}%
    \addcolon\addspace%
    }
```

If you now change the bibstyle to authortitle, you are a bit closer to what you need.

Comment: There are some subtleties to this approach. You have to think about `(min|max)bibnames` vs `(min|max)citenames`: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11827/35864 If you use a style with ibidem and compression you have to consider even more things.